# Writing a Hive UDF using jRuby

Tags: java, jruby, hive, user-defined-functions

Can it be done? Here's a test UDF I had tried writing:

```
java_package "com.foo.hive.udf"
java_import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description
java_import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF

java_annotation 'Description(name = "foo", value = "_FUNC_(string) - just returns test.")'
class Foo < UDF
  def evaluate ts
    "test"
  end
end
```

Then I compiled it like this:

```
jrubyc com/foo/hive/udf/Foo.rb
jar -cf Foo.jar com/foo/hive/udf/*.class /path/to/jruby-1.7.3/lib/jruby.jar
```

And then I try to use it:

```
hive> ADD JAR path/to/Foo.jar;
Added /path/to/Foo.jar to class path
hive> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION foo AS 'com.foo.hive.udf.Foo';
```

And that gives me:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/ast/executable/AbstractScript
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
  ...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
hive> ADD JAR /path/to/Foo.jar;
```

This same thing, written in java, works fine. So this seems like a jRuby issue to me?

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/ast/executable/AbstractScript` is telling you that the JRuby runtime jar is not available. When you compile a JRuby class, it creates a `.class` file that depends on the version of JRuby you compiled it with.

I'm guessing that if you downloaded the JRuby complete jar, you could run

```
> ADD JAR jruby-complete-1.7.4.jar
```

and then your class would have its dependencies configured.